# one session per user or one session in every users

Tags: session

I am curious about the value of `PHPSESSID` because, I created a simple login-type web app. When I try to login with different accounts, the value of the `PHPSESSID` is not changing. I got curious if it does okay or not. Because I tried to login in youtube with different account too. But their `SID's` differ on each user.

My question is:

1) Is what happening on my web app okay ?

2) Is yes, how can I make a session ids per account/user ?

3) If no, how can I fix it ?

I would really appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It partly depends on exactly how you implemented "login."  One way to do it is simply to change the user-identity (which, by definition, is part of the data that is stored in the session), while keeping the same session.

Another equally-valid way to do it is to first update the existing session (to show that the user, in that session, is now "logged off") *(maybe...)*, and then to coin a completely new session-id, thus starting an entirely new session, in which you now "log on."

One advantage of the second approach ... and probably the reason why so many sites do it this way ... has to do with the possibility that the user might wish to open a new browser-window, and to log-in to the application a second time, intending to keep *both* logins alive at the same time.  If the session-id token is part of the URL, or maybe is part of a hidden form or what-have-you, such that both session-id's *can* be retained independently, it becomes possible for the user to do what he has done without conflict.  Two parallel sessions exist.  In one, he is logged on as "joe," and in the second, he is logged on as "jeff."  And so on.  One set of browser-windows (somehow ...) carries the "jeff session" token; others carry the "joe session" token.

Fundamentally, a "session" is just a pool of server-side values, identified by the (`PHPSESSID` ...) token furnished each time by the client.  Exactly how you choose to manage it, is at your discretion.  It's a design-decision with no "correct" approach.

Comment: thanks for the response, i have additional question, my function on my logout is `unset`, then I researched on `php.net` that destroy is better, so what do you think ? Again thank you for your response, this help me so much

Comment: I'm not familiar with "destroy," and in any case it really won't matter.  What you've actually got to do is to remove or alter a particular hash-value ... a particular stored key that says "this user is logged on" ... within the session-store.  Then, you update the session-store to reflect that.  Next, if you like, you coin a new session-ID, initialize that new session-store entry appropriately, save it into the session-store, and return that newly-minted token to the user.  ### (N.B. by "store" I am referring to "storage," e.g. a database table, not a place of business!)